Database design to solve 2 OR foreign keys
Suppose I have a Postgres predefined_category table and a user_category table.
Where predefined_ means it's predefined by developers, and user_ means users can create any categories they want.
In the user_transaction table, there'll be a column to store a reference to a category, which can be either from predefined_ or user_ category.
However, databases are not smart enough to check if the value exists in one table, and then check the other.
Is there a pattern to resolve such cases?
Table predefined_category {
  id int pk
  name varchar
}

Table user_category {
  id int pk
  name varchar
}

Table user_transaction {
  id int pk
  amount numeric(12,2)
  category_id int [ref: - predefined_category.id, ref: - user_category.id]
}

Link to dbdiagram: https://dbdiagram.io/d/Public-Playground-6620854503593b6b6148a846

Use a single table for the category. And a category can be of type user or predefined

Thanks, that might actually solve the issue and more.
